# Adding a function to a variable in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around using a variable to store a function. I want to store the following function in a variable:

```
declare @agegroup int
set @agegroup = datediff(year, convert(date, p.date_of_birth), getdate())
```

Doing this produces an error:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I believe that this is happening because SQL doesn't know what p.date_of_birth is yet. It's a column from a table in a query.

```
select p.date_of_birth from person p
```

I will need to reference the function in the variable numerous times in the query (once it's complete), so I want to neaten up my query by using a variable. It this possible?

Edit: I was asked to include some data for the field in my sample code. The DOB is stored as a string: yyyymmdd

```
19350919
19370607
19370607
19400814
19410128
19410128
```

Comment: No, this is happening because you are storing a date as a string -- a no-no -- and then trying to convert it to a date.  The format is invalid.

Comment: Why isn't `date_of_birth` *already* a date?

Comment: `set @agegroup = datediff(year, convert(date, p.date_of_birth), getdate())` doing this will **NEVER** produce this error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: @Pரதீப் Really? What if `date_of_birth` is `'20180231'`?

Comment: The database I'm working with stores the date as a string, so it has to be converted to be proper format (or so I think). Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - If you look at the code closely, query is referring a table which is not part of that query. Invalid identifier is what the error should have been. Read the full question

Comment: @Pரதீப் I'm reading beyond the question. Do you think the OP is making up the error message, or do you think maybe they dumbed down the code sample?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand Sorry, I dumbed down the code. It's a long script. The error only pops up if I leave the variable in the script.

Comment: All those dates look ok; which implies (as we all expected) that there's a date in there that isn't valid (such as `'19750229'`). This is why storing a date as a `date` is so important. This query in going to look awful in a comment, but can you see what the following returns...

Comment: `SELECT date_of_birth
FROM person
WHERE (SUBSTRING(date_of_birth,3,2) IN ('01','03','05','07','08','10','12') AND CONVERT(int,RIGHT(date_of_birth,2)) NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 31)
   OR (SUBSTRING(date_of_birth,3,2) IN ('04','06','09','11') AND CONVERT(int,RIGHT(date_of_birth,2)) NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 30)
   OR (SUBSTRING(date_of_birth,3,2) IN ('02') AND CONVERT(int,RIGHT(date_of_birth,2)) NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 28) /*yes, I realise this isn't going to cover leap years*/
   OR LEN(date_of_birth) != 8;`

Comment: I think I see the problem. 18840218 and 19001212 might be a little out of normal range.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `SELECT CONVERT(date,'18840218');`. I'm still very much of mind that you have a fictitious date in your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I assume your code is taken out of context, because `p` is not defined.  That's okay.

Your problem is that `date_of_birth` is stored as a string.  Fix that problem, by storing it as a `date`.  SQL databases have date/time types for a reason.  Use them.

You can eliminate the error in your code by using `try_convert()`:

```
set @agegroup = datediff(year, try_convert(date, p.date_of_birth), getdate())
```

In SQL Server 2008, a reasonable approximation is:

```
set @agegroup = datediff(year, (case when isdate(p.date_of_birth) = 1 then p.date_of_birth end), getdate())
```

You can identify the offending values by doing:

```
select date_of_birth
from p
where try_convert(date, date_of_birth) is null and date_of_birth is not null;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Is there any way to get around this problem? I can't edit the structure of this table (it's proprietary). Can't I try converting the column to date in a var first?

Comment: @theeviininja He already showed you a way to get around the problem - add `try_convert()` to your query. Of course you could fix the data in the table, even if you can't fix the data types, but you'll have to do this over and over again unless you also put something in place to prevent more bad data from getting in there in the first place.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I forgot to mention that this is SQL Server 2008, not 2012, so Try_Convert isn't an option, unfortunately. I updated the title of my post.

Comment: @theeviininja . . . You should include sample data in the question so we know what the dates are supposed to look like.

Comment: @theeviininja On ancient versions like that you can use `CONVERT(date, CASE WHEN ISDATE(p.date_of_birth) = 1 THEN p.date_of_birth END)` which is essentially what `TRY_CONVERT()` is doing. But you need to (a) clean up the data (identify it with `WHERE ISDATE(date_of_birth) = 0`) and (b) go back to the vendor and tell them their design is moronic.